# Алгоритм Сортировки Слиянием на C++

Tags: c++, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием

Задача такая, реализовать алгоритм сортировки слияния, прочитав варианты реализации на других сайтах и версию вики, реализация показалась мне довольно громоздкой и не совсем элегантной, в собственной версии поставил себе задачу:
 - Выполнить рекурсивно.
 - Одной функцией.
 - Уменьшить число операнд.
 - Свести количество параметров до передаваемого в функцию указателя на массив и размера самого массива.
  После некоторых преобразований свел код, до ниже представленного, компилируется с ошибкой "stuck overflow: обращение к запрещенному участку памяти", или "нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу..".
Долгое время не могу найти утечку и прошу кого-либо более внимательного заметить и сказать мне, где именно происходит выход за пределы массива в данном коде:

```
void merge_sort(int* unsorted, unsigned int size)
{
    if (size < 2) return;

    unsigned int middle = size >> 1;

    merge_sort(unsorted, middle);
    merge_sort(unsorted + middle, size - middle);

    int* first = unsorted;
    int* second = unsorted + middle;

    int* sorted = new int[size];

    while (first != (unsorted + middle) && second != (unsorted + size))
        *sorted++ = *first < *second ? *first++ : *second++;

    while (first != (unsorted + middle))
        *sorted++ = *first++;
    while (second != (unsorted + size))
        *sorted++ = *second++;

    sorted -= size;
    while (unsorted != second)
        *unsorted++ = *sorted++;

    delete[] sorted;
}
```

- На данный момент: путем вывода значений в лог, обнаружил, функция работает корректно до последнего цикла, который по непонятным причинам становится бесконечным..
- Полностью рабочая версия. Спустя всего-то..

Comment: Почему `size >> 1`, а не нормальное человеческое `size / 2`? Откуда тут взялся сдвиг?

Comment: `size >> 1` <=> `size / 2^1`, что по сути быстрее и отсутствует неявное преобразование типов double to int в случае `size / 2`

Comment: Во-первых, это нисколько не "быстрее", ибо для `unsigned int` эти варианты абсолютно строго эквивалентны. Никогда в C/С++ коде нет смысла вручную "оптимизировать" целочисленное деление или умножение на константу времени компиляции. А уж "оптимизировать" деление на 2 - это грубейшая профанация. Во-вторых, какой еще "double to int"??? Где вы тут увидели double???

Comment: В вашем коде наблюдаются какие-то дикие попытки экономить на переменных.  Не надо этого делать. Заведите в два раза больше переменных со своими четкими ролями, и код станет намного удобочитаемее.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо за совет, но так будет нечестно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- (Уже исправлено.) Ошибка в условии первого цикла

  ```
  while (first != (unsorted + middle) || second != (unsorted + size))
      *sorted++ = *first < *second ? *first++ : *second++;
  ```

  приведет к вылету за пределы массива из-за `||` в условии. Тут, очевидно, нужно `&&`, а не `||`.
- (Уже исправлено.) Очевидная ошибка при обработке "хвоста" массива

  ```
  while (second != (unsorted + middle))
      *sorted++ = *second++;
  ```

  У вас `second` должен идти до `unsorted + size`, а не до `unsorted + middle`, как вы сами прекрасно знаете, судя по условию первого цикла.
- (Уже исправлено.) Далее написана вообще какая-то полнейшая бессмыслица

  ```
  while (sorted != (sorted - size))
      *(unsorted-- + size) = *sorted--;
  ```

  Условие этого цикла всегда истинно, если `size` не равно 0. То есть это бесконечный цикл. Что вы хотели этим сказать?
- (Уже исправлено.) Ваш "замысел" с последним циклом понятен (хоть и реализован криво), однако, кроме бессмысленного условия, страдает и от других косяков. А именно:

  - После предыдущих циклов указатель `sorted` указывает на "мусорное" значение после последнего записанного. В последнем цикле ваше копирование из `*sorted--` будет на первом шаге копировать это "мусорное" значение. Так как ваш цикл задуман как делающий ровно нужное количество итераций - `size` - то ясно, что он где-то "потеряет" какое-то нужное значение.
  - К указателю `unsorted` применяется `--`. Кто вам разрешил это делать? Указатель `unsorted` может указывать на начало некоего массива. Адресная арифметика в С++ не разрешает "выгонять" указатель влево за начало массива.

Comment: программа вылетает на именно первом цикле, со сравнением, простите за сырой код, там механическая ошибка копипасты в первом случае, где вы указали, а "нелепица" имеет по моему такой смысл: после предыдущей инкрементации в цикле, указатель sorted указывает на последний элемент подмассива, поэтому я присваиваю в обратном порядке, чтобы не переприсваивать ему лишний раз адресс первого элемента.

Comment: добавлю, что копирование второго хвоста излишнее, а последний `while()`,  очевидно крайне кривое копирование элементов в исходный массив.

Comment: @PostPunkTheSmith, `(sorted - size)` вычисляется на **каждой** итерации цикла заново.

Comment: @PostPunkTheSmith: Добавил: в первом цикле в условии должно быть `&&`, а не `||`. Потому у вас и происходит вылет за пределы массива в первом цикле. Что касается `while (sorted != (sorted - size))` - у вас какое-то непонимание основ языка наблюдается. Условие `sorted != (sorted - size)` - всегда истинно и цикл -
 бесконечен.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ведь при обработке хвоста мы не знаем наверняка, какой из подмассивов именно содержит остаток, поэтому, чтобы избежать лишнего `if()` я поставил два цикла с предусловием, поэтому если один из указателей указывает на последний элемент подмассива, то один из циклов просто не начнется, а сработает именно нужный

Comment: @PostPunkTheSmith, хвост второго массива **уже** находится по нужным адресам... в итоге этот  цикл сначала копирует его в sorted, а затем следующий (если бы он был правильным) опять отправляет его обратно один в один.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, там либо указатель `first` указывает на конец своего подмассива, либо `second`, так что по условию не сработает либо предусловие первого цикла, либо второго, либо я не понимаю свой код, но в этом замысел.

Comment: @PostPunkTheSmith: Все правильно, но пока вы не "врубитесь", что в такой реализации в условии главного цикла должно быть `&&`, а не `||`, прогресса не будет.

Comment: @AnT, за это спасибо, можете оформить, как ответ, в остальном, я думаю, здесь вопрос арифметики указателей..

Comment: @PostPunkTheSmith: Все уже давно оформлено как ответ. Вы, видимо, просто не читаете.

Comment: @PostPunkTheSmith: Подразумевая, что **необходимо** исправить ошибки о которых пишет AnT, всё так и есть: выполняется только один из этих двух циклов. И это будет работать. Но от второго цикла **можно** избавится, сократив тем самым издержки на копирование в sorted и обратно.

Comment: @Fat-Zer: Логично. Два цикла, следующие за главным циклом, должны копировать данные прямо в массив `unsorted`. Копировать их сначала в `sorted`, а потом оттуда в `unsorted` - это бессмысленное переливание туда-сюда. Но это уже оптимизация. Сначала можно было бы заставить заработать существующий вариант.

Comment: @AnT, я на самом деле тоже просмотрел, что хвост первого массив можно напрямую перегонять =)